# Django template dir strange behaviour

Tags: python, django

I am really having problems to set TEMPLATE_DIR correctly after searching through bunch of topics and trying various things.

Here are my project settings:

```
#settings.py
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''

STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/static/',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/TrainingBook/templates/',
    PROJECT_PATH + '/RestClient/templates/',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'TrainingBook',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.debug",
    "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
    "django.core.context_processors.media",
    "django.core.context_processors.static",
    # 'django.core.context_processors.request',
    "TrainingBook.context_processors.global_context",
)
print PROJECT_PATH # /Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient
print STATICFILES_DIRS # ('/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/static/',)
print TEMPLATE_DIRS 
# ('/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/TrainingBook/templates/',
# '/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/RestClient/templates/')
```

My project structure:

```
$ pwd
/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient
$ tree
.
├── RestClient
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── home.html
│   │   └── login_form.html
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── TrainingBook
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── context_processors.py
│   ├── context_processors.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── friends.html
│   │   ├── statistics.html
│   │   └── workouts.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
├── settings.pyc
└── static
    ├── css
    │   ├── bootstrap-glyphicons.css
    │   ├── bootstrap.css
    │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   └── main.css
    └── js
        ├── bootstrap.js
        ├── bootstrap.min.js
        └── jquery-1.10.2.js
```

I moved "settings.py" one level up in order to get PROJECT_PATH set to "/RestClient/" instead of "/RestClient/RestClient/".

I also modified manage.py from

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "RestClient.settings")
```

to

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")
```

When I run server TemplateDoesNotExist is raised and I am seeing something strange:

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/TrainingBook/templates/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/RestClient/templates/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
/Users/Kuba/.virtualenvs/client/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/TrainingBook/templates/templates/home.html (File does not exist)
```

As you can see there is "/templates/templates" even though I didn't specify it so.

On the other hand if I switch TEMPLATE_DIRS to:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH + '/TrainingBook/',
    PROJECT_PATH + '/RestClient/',
)
```

after TemplateDoesNotExist is raised I can see that loader was looking for templates at:

```
/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/RestClient/home.html
/Users/Kuba/Development/University/RestClient/TrainingBook/home.html
```

What did I do wrong?

EDIT: The problem was that I defined some views like this:

```
class Home(Base):
    template_name = 'templates/home.html'
```

Comment: Just noticed `settings.pyc` in `RestClient` dir - what if you delete it?

Comment: Didn't help, plus it is recreated after I rerun server.

Comment: btw that file will come back if the process got write access. its the python compiled file...

Comment: So it's probably RestClient/settings.py that's get loaded then. Try setting your correct template path in that one.

Comment: There is no RestClient/setting.py, I moved it one level up. I didn't notice there is RestClient/setting.pyc left there. Already removed it, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Well the problem was that I set template_name in my view to smth like: '/templates/home.html'.

Answer (score 1):

You specified `templates/home.html` instead of just `home.html`.

A template name will be appended to a TEMPLATE_DIRS, so `/foo/templates/` as TEMPLATE_DIRS will become `/foo/templates/templates/home.html` if `templates/home.html` is a template name. Instead, the template name should be just `home.html` and the resulting template path would be `/foo/templates/home.html` which is correct.